# Pass a date from Excel VBA to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

When passing a date using the following:

```
SQL_TXT = SQL_TXT & "'" & UCase(Trim(x.Offset(0, 4))) & "'," & vbCrLf
```

I get Conversion failed when converting from string

Comment: `iif(isdate(Trim(x.Offset(0, 4)),Trim(x.Offset(0, 4)),UCase(Trim(x.Offset(0, 4))) )`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if a date is actually being passed or it is being passed as characters. 
Something like what nathan mentioned can be used and tested

```
iif(
isdate(Trim(x.Offset(0, 4)),Trim(x.Offset(0, 4)),UCase(Trim(x.Offset(0, 4)))
)
```